# Persisting Log entity using another EntityManager

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

I have second connection and entity manager configured for logging only. It works fine in my logging service, but there is a problem with:

```
$user = $this->security->getUser();
$log->setUser($user);
```

When trying this I've got "A new entity was found through the relationship" exception. And it's ok, because second entity manager doesn't know about User and is trying to cascade persist object (which is not configured). In previous version of Symfony (3.x I guess) I used this workaround (from my previous version of code):

```
$user = $token->getUser();
$userManaged = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->find($user->getId());
$log->setUser($userManaged);
```

It worked, but now (Symfony 6.0.7) it no longer works. I'm trying now:

```
    $user = $this->security->getUser();
    if($user){
        $userManaged = $em->getRepository('App:User')->find($user->getId());
        $log->setUser($userManaged);            
    }
```

And still having "A new entity was found through the relationship".

How should I do this in proper way? Here is my doctrine.yml ORM section:

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default                
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
            auto_mapping: true
            mappings:
                App: ~
                    is_bundle: false
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity'
                    alias: App
        log:
            connection: log
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
            mappings:
                App:
                    is_bundle: false
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity'
                    alias: App
```

Comment: Is $log your "log entity manager"? If yes where comes from the function "setUser" on it?

Comment: Symfony/Doctrine is basically broke when you have the same entity type mapped to more than one entity.  In early days it worked okay but with the addition of the ServiceEntityRepository it does not.  User will always be queried using the first entity manager that maps it.  You would actually have similar problems with Log if you tried to query it.  You basically need to remove the Doctrine relationship between log and user.

Comment: Solution was using` $em->merge` instead of old workaround. `$log->setUser($em->merge($user));` . Now everything is working great.